# PHP MySQL Prepared Statement Doesn't Fetch from View

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I finished developing my website on my local PC, and it's working fine. Now, after I shifted the PHP scripts and file to my web host directory, I started facing issues especially with Prepared Statements.

Briefly, when I execute prepared statement against a table, it returns value, but when executing it against a view, it doesn't.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($a["server"], $a["username"], $a["password"], $a["database"]);

$sql = "SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ALIAS = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET["alias"]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

echo "ID: $id";
```

$id has value, but when I select from view

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM view WHERE ALIAS = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET["alias"]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

echo "ID: $id";
```

$id is empty, and if I select from view using mysqli_query(), then it would get a value. Can you please help in resolving this issue.

Note: at beginning I set

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
```

Thanks

Comment: When you switched environs... are you sure the views are all setup correctly to the correct tables? Does doing the sql statement manually in mysql present you with the correct result? (and don't turn off error reporting when you run into issues ;)

Comment: Use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` to see if has any error being silently supressed.

Comment: If you use a non prepared statement with the view on the remote server it works?

Comment: Thanks all for your support. If I use non prepared statement, the query gets result easily and smoothly. Also, the view fetches the records correctly when I check it at phpmyadmin. I set my mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL). I put the code in try catch block, and when executing prepared statement against DB table, I received exception for missing index, then I added index for column ALIAS, and it worked fine. Now, when I fetch data from view, I get the exception "Caught exception: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared"

Comment: I think a temporary solution that I will join database tables while executing the prepared statements. Unfortunately, I'm not utilizing the views. This exception seems long lasting error, and there is not enough discussion covering it, or resolving it.